# Can I make a calculated column that uses text in the boolean comparison but returns a number?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column

I'm trying to make a calculated column with a 5 level conditional as follows:

```
=SI([Impacto Inherente]="Crítico";400;(SI([Impacto Inherente]="Mayor";300;(SI([Impacto Inherente]="Moderado";200;(SI([Impacto Inherente]="Menor";100;(SI([Impacto Inherente]="Insignificante";50;0)))))))))
```

This worked perfectly fine in Excel and I think it's properly written, but I keep geeting a sintax error. I've tried commas instead of semi-colons, I've tried it in english (IF), I've tried just one of the clauses... It always tells me there's a sintax error. Could the issue be with the fact that I'm using a text column in the conditional comparison but trying to return a numerical value?

Although I tried to return the number as a string and it didn't work either. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Create a **Choice column** named [Impacto Inherente]

[image]

2.Create a **Calculated column** named [CalTest1] and use the below **Formula**:

```
=IF([Impacto Inherente]="Crítico",400,IF([Impacto Inherente]="Mayor",300,IF([Impacto Inherente]="Moderado",200,IF([Impacto Inherente]="Menor",100,IF([Impacto Inherente]="Insignificante",50,0)))))
```

[image]

3.Here is my test:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! What finally did work was using IF with semicolons the next day... which I had already tried they day I posted. I think the entire Microsoft architecture is just finnicky like that. Even your solution is the same, just with less parenthesis. Some days it just doesn't collaborate with you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved.